# how to create (initialize) a std::tuple from an array when the constructors have the same argument type (a file path)

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

I have some classes all having a constructor that takes a file path. I would like to create a std::tuple of them from the argv argument in the main function. Here is a sketch

```cpp
class A { 
  public:
  A(const char *); // Taking a file path
};

class B {
  public:
  B(const char *); // Taking a file path
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto tup(myCreateTuple<A, B, A>(argc, argv)); 
  // myCreateTuple would in this case use argv[1], argv[2]
  // and argv[3] to create A(argv[1]), B(argv[2]) and A(argv[3]). 
  // argc is just passed along to verify that argv is long enough.
  // tup would have of the type std::tuple<A ,B, A>
}
```

The order in which the tuple members are created is not important (i.e. the execution order of the constructors is allowed to be undefined). Do you have an idea of how to  implement myCreateTuple?

I guess it would be possible to avoid myCreateTuple all together and instead use

```cpp
std::tuple<A, B, A> tup{ A(argv[1]), B(argv[2]), A(argv[3]) };
```

but that would be a less generic solution.

Comment: Searching for a question

Comment: I now changed "i am interested how I should" into "Do you have an idea of how to". I formulated my question as a small implementation problem because I think it will be easier for others to follow what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`<redi/index_tuple.h>`](http://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h) to provide a compile-time integer sequence that produces the array indices in a pack expansion:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <assert.h>
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

template<typename... T, unsigned... I>
inline std::tuple<T...>
myCreateTuple_impl(char** argv, redi::index_tuple<I...>)
{
  return std::tuple<T...>(argv[I+1]...);
}

template<typename... T>
inline std::tuple<T...>
myCreateTuple(int argc, char** argv)
{
  assert(argc > sizeof...(T));
  return myCreateTuple_impl<T...>(argv, redi::to_index_tuple<T...>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do the classes A and B need to have a default constructor or a copy constructor too? Or is it enough with just A(const char *)?

Comment: Is there any difference if you "return std::tuple<T...>(argv[I+1]...);" or "return std::tuple<T...>{argv[I+1]...};"?

Comment: `A` and `B` need to be MoveConstructible (or CopyConstructible) but do not need to be DefaultConstructible. In this case there's no difference between using () or {} initialization, the same tuple constructor will be called.

Comment: Is MoveConstructibility or CopyConstructibility a general requirement for std::tuple members? Just being curious, in my case I have a CopyConstructor.

Comment: Only if you want to move or copy the tuple, but since you usually want to do that then it's usually a requirement. If you want to default construct a tuple then its elements need to be DefaultConstructible.

Answer (score 1):

Create a compile time sequence of ints of values 1 2 3 (or 0 1 2) from the number of types you pass in.

Then reference both the sequence as an index into the array and setters into the tuple using ... syntax.  Or put the ... in a constructor call directly with the int sequence dereferencing the array.

Comment: Thanks, I guess Jonathan Wakely followed the second of your alternative solutions: "in a constructor call directly with the int sequence dereferencing the array".

Comment: @erik The price of posting from a smart phone: code is hard to type. :)